# Project Point to Line on grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I'm using QGIS 3.22 and I need some help.
I have a lots of points to move and I would like to find an automatic way of doing it. I have a shapefile of points (Dark Green) on a grid, and I want to move them to the nearest Line (light green) and keep the point on the red grid.

Do you have any idea of how to do this ?

I know how to do manually but I would like to make it faster.
I do have a grid and I would like to move points along the X axis to a Line. I'm using the snapping option and advance digitizing option to do it. I can
manually but is there a way to write a script or to make it more automatic? I have thousand points to move.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly in your input, but you should either use y = ax + b (lienar function) or ctgX = a/b (right triangle equation)

Comment: @FlashThunder My input is a shape file with thousands of points. Imagine I have a street (like the light green line) and I want to move the dark green points (lets say less than 300 meters away) to the green line following a specific angle (always the same for my project)

Comment: What GIS software are you using to do this manually?  What are the precise steps you do to do that?

Comment: This looks like what you are after: https://medium.com/@brendan_ward/how-to-leverage-geopandas-for-faster-snapping-of-points-to-lines-6113c94e59aa

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual layer to:

1 - Join the grid to your green layer and intersect them to get a point at each intersection with grid id.

2 - Do the same with the grid and your point layer to attach grid id to each point

3 - Join these together by grid id.

You need a unique id field on each layer. Adjust field and layer names below. And you might need to choose a higher distance than 2 m if your points arent on top of your grid:

```sql
select pointid, newlocation as geom from 
--First find the intersection points of the grid and road, a table of grid id and point geometries
(select t1.id as gridid, st_intersection(t1.geometry, t2.geometry) as newlocation from grid t1
join road t2
on PtDistWithin(t1.geometry, t2.geometry, 2)) sub1
join
--Join each grid id to the points (the ones you want to move)
(select t1.id as gridid, t2.*, t2.id as pointid from grid t1
--Then join the intersection points to these by grid id
join points t2
on PtDistWithin(t1.geometry, t2.geometry, 2)) sub2
on sub1.gridid = sub2.gridid
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, I will save a lot of time but is there a way to do the same and after that using the geometry of the "newpoints" layer and update the orignal shape "points" ?And can we also set up an offset limit in order to not create points if the intersect point is more than X meters (to far away form the original position) ?

Comment: Do you have postgis?

Comment: No I don't but I think I need to go learn about postgis

Comment: I think it should be possible anyway. Join (under Layer properties of your point layer) the output virtual layer to your original point layer, and move the points with Field Calculator, I have not tried it though

Comment: I tried to add the geometry in the virtual layer but I'm not expert in sql. Do you know how can I include the geometry in your sql query ?

Comment: I'd like to revise my inquiry :) I'm now exploring the use of PostGIS for performing this offset task. Does anyone have guidance on how to achieve this with PostGIS? My objective is to shift points along a line. Ideally, I would like to be able to select the specific line (road) for moving my points and also have the option to choose the angle for projecting the points. Thanks